# Change of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I just read this:

Let *X* be a discrete random variable whose probability function is $f(x)$. Suppose that a discrete random variable *U* is defined in terms of *X* by $U = \phi(X)$, where to each value of *X* there corresponds one and only one value of *U* and conversely, so that $X = \psi (U)$. Then the probability function for *U* is given by $g(u) = f [\psi(u)]$.

Is this correct? This is from Schaum's  Probability and Statistics 4th edition pg42.

Can any of you please help me understand this? I am sorry I am a bit weak in Probability. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. There exists a one-to-one mapping between X and U which can be undone or inverted. So the probability functions for both X and U take the exact same shape.

For e.g U could be as simple as a scaled version of X , e.g U = 2X.